# Links in pdf not working?

Tags: hyperref

None of the links I create work in the sense that they're not clickable. The preamble is this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=green,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
 \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
 \numberwithin{mydef}{subsection}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{thm}{subsection}

\title{test}
\author{test}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you using `latex` or `pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex`?

Comment: Pretty hard to say much since you don't show how you are trying to create links... Did you compile twice?

Comment: I'm using dvi2pdf. The links aren't working the in the table of contents either.

Comment: After the preamble above I have 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\section{test}
\subsection{test}

Comment: @user69751: Please add that `\maketitle...` stuff to your post above

Comment: @user69751: If you use `dvipdf`, then `latex` is your compilation executable -- you have to run twice, as cfr asked. If you see the warning:  `Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.`, this is an indicator

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using `pdflatex` directly?

Comment: For anyone who came here through searching: make sure that in your PDF reader you did not select "Text Selection" or anything similar. In Okular, for example, that makes links not clickable. Switch to "Browse" mode instead and links become clickable again. I made this mistake and was confused at first.

Answer (score 6):

I stripped your MWE down a bit and add one hyperlink to the equation. I compiled it twice with `pdflatex`. The result is as expected:  hyperlinks work! My test file is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
%    \usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea} 
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{ colorlinks, citecolor=green, filecolor=black, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue } 
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    1+1=2
    \end{equation}

\newpage
Does hyperref work? Of course, see \eqref{eq:1}.

\end{document}
```

For hyperlinks to other elements of documents (section titles, theorems, etc) it should be the same. How this works when `dvi-ps-pdf` is used, I don't know. I never use it.